# Aligning the number of bins and number of edges in pandas.cut in python (getting error: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges)

Tags: python, pandas

In python, I am using pandas.cut to categorize values into bins but I'm getting an error that I just can't get to the bottom of / work around.

Just as context, I am using dataset #1 to define the bins/edges for various 'parameters'. Then applying those to dataset #2. The list of edges is in 'list_of_edges' and the names of the bins is in 'names_of_bins' for each parameter in a dictionary. The last edge is always np.inf.

I use the following code that is supposed to run for 40-50 iterations. It runs fine but then it gets to a point and gives me an error.

`'ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges'`

However, I've made sure that the bin labels are one fewer than the number of edges. So then I put a try/except around the code to print the number of edges and number of bins when there is an exception. But that shows that the number of bins is indeed one fewer than the number of edges.

Here's the code with exception handling:

```
     for parameter in parameters_for_quantiles:
        list_of_edges = bin_edges_dict[parameter]
        names_of_bins = bin_names_dict[parameter]
        try: 
            test_price_df_dict[symbol][parameter+'_Quantile.1'] = pd.cut(test_price_df_dict[symbol][parameter], list_of_edges, labels=names_of_bins, include_lowest = True, duplicates = 'drop' )
        except ValueError: 
            print("Error!!!! Number of Edges: {0}, Number of Bins: {1}".format(len(list_of_edges), len(names_of_bins)))
            print(list_of_edges)
            print(names_of_bins)
```

Here's the output of the code showing that # of bins is indeed 1 fewer than number of edges:

```
Error!!!! Number of Edges: 11, Number of Bins: 10
[-0.005, -0.001, -0.001, -0.001, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, inf]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Error!!!! Number of Edges: 11, Number of Bins: 10
[-0.029, -0.002, -0.001, -0.001, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, inf]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

(Interestingly, the error only shows up where then there are 11 edges and 10 bins. Not for all iterations where there are 11 edges and 10 bins but when I do get an error, it is one of the iterations with 11 edges and 10 bins).

I'm really confused and not sure how to work around this. I've toggled 'include_lowest' and duplicates but doesn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Aren't your edges supposed to be unique?

Comment: Aarrghhh.. Of course. I first spent a fair bit of time making sure the edges were unique... BUT... then I eventually started rounding the edges to three decimal places which caused  them to be the same. Thanks!!!